# Should I store 1 DB record per page view or 1 record per day to generate report of daily page view counts

Tags: php, mysql

As part of an A/B Testing plugin I am building for WordPress.  I store the number of page views on a page for each A/B test variation of that page.

If a page has 4 variations, then each time that page is viewed I will add +1 to the counter on that page ID +  Variation ID that is being viewed.

I want to be able to show the views count data in a graph similar to this one that GitHub uses below...

[image]

another example from StackOverflow stats...

[image]

[image]

---

So my question is:

Should i record a new database record for each page visit which would have the page ID, variation ID, and Date

or should I instead create 1 DB record every day for each page variation and then increment its number on each additional page view for that day.  On the next day, repeat and create a new record for that day.  This method would make the DB much smaller as the max number of DB records would be the number of AB test variations x 1 within a day.  The other method on 4 variations would have 4 x number of pages views for that day

4 variations using the 1st version with 100 views for the day would create 100 DB records in 1 day.  The 2nd version with the same number of views would only create 4 DB records.

I know there are pros and cons to both methods but I am asking as I do not really know what they are.

My end goal is to simply generate a PHP array where each day of the year is a key in the array and has a matching value which will hold the number of views for that day on the page variation I am viewing.

```
$page_1_variation_1 = array(
  1 => 12,
  2 => 23,
  3 => 44,
  4 => 0,
  5 => 1,
  6 => 2,
  7 => 43,
  8 => 15,
  9 => 4,
  10 => 22,
);


$page_1_variation_2 = array(
  1 => 12,
  2 => 23,
  3 => 44,
  4 => 0,
  5 => 1,
  6 => 2,
  7 => 43,
  8 => 15,
  9 => 4,
  10 => 22,
);


$page_1_variation_3 = array(
  1 => 12,
  2 => 23,
  3 => 44,
  4 => 0,
  5 => 1,
  6 => 2,
  7 => 43,
  8 => 15,
  9 => 4,
  10 => 22,
);
```

Comment: If you ever need some other statistic (like how often user visits) than go with **#1**, if you only need to track visits count per day - **#2**. I would go with **#1**

Comment: @Justinas I am also considering doing #1 and then also with a daily cron job building #2 as a summary table which would calculate 1 time daily from #1's data

Comment: So why asking than?

Comment: @Justinas I just thought of it as I typed it!  My concern is the 1st table growing too large over long term.  So I would like to be able to prune it like every couple of months.  If I went with both methods then I could prune table 1 and always have the data I need in the 2nd table for my reports.  Also I am curious as to how other projects handle this scenario like the sample images I posted so I am open to hearing other solutions

Comment: IMHO, the mixture of both is the right way to do it. Save an entry for each visit for the current day, have a nightly cron job aggregate these values for you to minimise database size. This is the way other statistics software like PIWIK are working as well.